# Export a file listing from DM5 (opentext)

Tags: directory-listing, opentext, file-listing

I have a folder structure in our DM. How can I export a list of subfolders and all files?

In DOS (*gag) I could do a "Dir star.star /s>list.txt" to get a list. Is there a way do get this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Direct from OpenText support.

The application does not have such option.

### It is not possible to export the folder information.

Unbelievable.